If multiplying real numbers with quaternions is commutative is aibj = abij valid
When you multiply out a quaternion multiplication you may see stuff like aibj, i know ij = -ji = k but what about the real numbers a and b? Is it valid to make this substitution aibj = abij?

Ignoring the $a$ on the left and the $j$ on the right, we can just focus on whether $ib=bi$. And yes, this equality holds. As you know from standard complex arithmetic, real numbers commute with $i$.
And more generally, yes, for quaternions $p,q$, where $p$ happens to be real, we do always have $pq=qp$.
